# Passing a parameter to function

Tags: swift3, target-action, xcode8

//This is the function which contain my button action programatically

```
func didSetCategory(info: FitnessCenterModel) {
    myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(Function(d: info)), for: .touchUpInside)    
     }
```

//  my selector function for the button target

```
func Function(d:FitnessCenterModel ) {
print(info)
}
```

but i am not able to pass as the compiler is throwing an error **"Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@Objc' method, property, or initialzer**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A selector does not refer to a method *call*, but just the *method* itself.

What you are doing here:

```
#selector(Function(d: info))
```

is passing an argument to `Function` and creating a selector from this. You can't do this. A selector must have no arguments. So how do you pass the `info` parameter then?

Create a property in your class called `selectedCategory`:

```
var selectedCategory: FitnessCenterModel!
```

Before you call `addTarget`, assign `info` to the above property:

```
selectedCategory = info
```

Create another method that calls `Function` with the parameter.

```
func buttonClicked() {
    Function(d: selectedCategory)
}
```

Change your `addTarget` call to use a `buttonClicked` as a selector:

```
#selector(buttonClicked)
```

Comment: Thanks@sweeper, would you tell me more about this problem..?

Comment: @AnilKumar What problem? Do you have as specific question that is related post? If yes then feel free to ask!

Comment: Like the question is we can pass a sender as a parameter to selector , but why can't we pass a parameter the same way..?

Comment: @AnilKumar _You_ don't pass the sender. The _button_ passes the sender. As the provider of a selector, you don't pass anything.

Comment: so passing a sender is  optional ..?

Comment: @AnilKumar By doing `#selector(someFunc(sender:))` you are not passing the sender. The `sender:` bit is actually pretty redundant unless you have multiple functions called `someFunc`. Writing "`sender:`" is optional but the button will always pass a sender. If your function does not have a parameter, then the passed sender will just get discarded.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the concept and giving your valuable time..:-)